# checking user input for right value in C++

Tags: c++, user-input

I have a requirment that accepts values from user input. It can be integers or strings. User input is accepted as below.

```
string strArg;
cout << "Enter price value "  << endl;
std::getline(std::cin, strArg);
int input;
std::stringstream(strArg) >> input;
```

Question is how do i check user has entered integer, rather than string, i.e., check for right input. How can we do this in portable way in C++? As in my project Boost is not allowed as my manager is not happy in using it:)

Comment: If they are not happy with existing libraries, you have to build your own and use those.

Comment: Your example is broken, as you changed `strArg` to `input` in the last line. And `RtsString` is not C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << "input:" << std::endl; 
  std::string input;
  std::getline(std::cin, input);

  std::istringstream str(input);
  int iv = 0;
  // this checks that we've read in an int and we've consumed the entire input, else
  // treat as string.
  if (str >> iv && str.tellg() == input.length())
  {
    std::cout << "int: " << iv << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "string: " << input << std::endl;
  }     

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can u pls eloborate, is that mean if we consume entire input is it int, if not is it string. for string don't we consume entire input.

Comment: eh? from the given `input` string, the above checks to see if the read in int (`iv`) has consumed the whole string, if it has, then it is considered an `int`, else it's a `string`. If `int`, `iv` contains the integer value, else `input` contains the string value. The check handles cases like: `123foo`, is this a string or int? if you simply did `str >> iv`, you'll get `iv=123`, is that what you want? Anyway - this does not seem like a work related problem, be honest - is this homework?

Comment: thanks for the help. my another question is does above logic handles input fooabc for int values. No this is not homework, this is part of req at work. And another point is i am getting compilation error for if check that tellg can not check for length

Answer (score 2):

There is no real reason to go through stringstream except you do not need to clear it if the user enters something invalid, plus you can echo it back to them..

```
int arg;
while(! (cin >> arg) )
{
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

   // tell the user their value was invalid
}

// now we have a valid number
```

If you allow the user to enter integers or strings but just behave differently when it is a string you can of course use istringstream.

Note that you may wish to check your stream is empty after reading the number in case the user entered 123XYZ which if you just streamed in would be considered "valid" as it starts with an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::stringstream and operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) and check if the conversion was successful.

---

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << "1234";

    int a = 0;
    ss >> a;
    if ( ss.fail() )
    {
        std::cout << "it is not a number" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u pls give an example how we can use this?

Comment: @user519882: You should take a moment to look at the examples on the page to which VJo linked you. Programming takes some effort. (Though cplusplus.com is not recommended as a good resource for language newcomers.)

Comment: @user519882 Sure, I added an example. Try changing the string and see what is the output.

Comment: @Tomalak You are right. I didn't expect people would have problems grasping the reference pages.

Answer (score 0):

boost::lexical_cast is apprximately the same as doing:

```
std::stringstream i; i << strArg;
int k; i >> k;
```

Comment: how are we checking for right input here? can u pls eloborate

Comment: With exceptions. Look up `boost::lexical_cast` and follow the documentation/examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may use regular expressions to check it. As far as I know, new C++ standart has support of regular expressions

Comment: Yes, but it's not a standard yet. Using it in production code would be silly.